# Routing initials conflicts in zf2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

My problem is about routing in Zend Framework 2. In my ZF2 application, older router was like `route => '/app/[:/someParams]'`. Now, I'm trying to make dynamic for my site for example about-us. I'm using unique slug name for dynamic pages. Every thing works fine. But when that url becomes like `/application` then it identifies as a first route. So, route conflicts are happening.

Comment: I'm confused about segment and literal in routing type. Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **priority** if conflicts happen

priority with high rank is the highest priority for the router to check the right route.

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'priority' => 100,             // <----
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
             ),
         ),
      ),
   ),
```

about the route you describe, use **Segment** to define some parameters (:/SomeParams)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How priority works? I mean, what is difference between priority value 1 and 100 ?

Comment: Hi Remi, another small question, as per your answer, admin router is having priority of 100 and now, as per my question, if url becomes /admin/param then what priority should I give?

Comment: Or else how to access child route ??